# Problem of reversed coordinates (XY) when importing WFS data with st_read

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I am trying to use French spatial data distributed using WFS. I want to use these data in a Shiny app that allows the user to update the data, so I would really prefer to use WFS and not only to embed the data from a shapefile in the app.

I can get the data but there is something off with it in the sense that the coordinates seem to have been reversed (X instead of Y and Y instead of X) resulting in a strange picture of France. I am not very familiar with the details of spatial analyses and data and I am certainly missing something.

I imported the data using the function st_read which I fed with the link to the WFS service. Then I get the upside-down map of French hydrographic network. When I connect QGIS using the same WFS link, however, the map is correct so I guess that sf and QGIS do not exactly handle things in the same way, but investigating why is beyond my knowledge.

When looking at the bounding box we see that the values returned for the x correspond to what we expect for the y and vice versa.

I had the problem with two different data sets distributed using WFS by the same provider (http://www.sandre.eaufrance.fr/). The first one was displaying points and the data contained XY coordinates so I removed the geometry and transformed the data frame using st_as_sf with the names of the X and Y fields in the coords parameter. This is a dirty workaround but it does not work with my second data set that has a MULTILINESTRING geometry. So I would prefer a clean way of importing/transforming the data in the correct format.

Here is a minimal code example to reproduce the unexpected behavior.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

data <- st_read("http://services.sandre.eaufrance.fr/geo/zon_FXX?Request=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0",
                layer = "SegClassContinuiteEco_Liste2",
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

st_bbox(data)

ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = data)
```

The code above gives this map:
[wrong map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDG5z.png)

The correct map should look like that (I rotated and flipped the original):
[correct map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4bc5.jpg)

My sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] sf_0.7-3        forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.0.1   purrr_0.3.2    
 [6] readr_1.3.1     tidyr_0.8.3     tibble_2.1.1    ggplot2_3.1.1   tidyverse_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.3.1     compiler_3.5.3  
 [5] plyr_1.8.4       class_7.3-15     tools_3.5.3      jsonlite_1.6    
 [9] lubridate_1.7.4  gtable_0.3.0     nlme_3.1-137     lattice_0.20-38 
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.3.4      DBI_1.0.0        cli_1.1.0       
[17] rstudioapi_0.10  yaml_2.2.0       haven_2.1.0      e1071_1.7-1     
[21] withr_2.1.2      xml2_1.2.0       httr_1.4.0       fs_1.2.7        
[25] generics_0.0.2   hms_0.4.2.9001   classInt_0.3-1   grid_3.5.3      
[29] tidyselect_0.2.5 glue_1.3.1       R6_2.4.0         fansi_0.4.0     
[33] readxl_1.3.1     modelr_0.1.4     magrittr_1.5     usethis_1.5.0   
[37] units_0.6-2      backports_1.1.4  scales_1.0.0     rvest_0.3.2     
[41] assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_1.4-1 utf8_1.1.4       stringi_1.4.3   
[45] lazyeval_0.2.2   munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.5.2      crayon_1.3.4
```

Thank you for any advice you could provide me.

Cédric

Comment: Is this a really big file or is it hard to get a connection? Alternatively I have slow internet.

Comment: This is quite a big file (but the smallest of those I have to work with)

Comment: I couldn't download the file after 15 mins. Hopefully you get an answer. Otherwise, maybe https://gis.stackexchange.com/ is the place to post it.

Comment: Thank you for trying, I realized that I have the wrong layer in the code (SegClassContinuiteEco_Liste1) which is larger than the one I intended to include in the example (SegClassConitnuiteEco_Liste2). I edited my post accordingly. However, this does not explain the very long time it takes for you. For me, the large layer is downloaded in about 20s and the small one in about 10s. I will also post this problem in gis.stackexchange. Thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

I also cannot download your data. To swap y and x you may want to try

```
d = st_geometry(data)
drev = d * matrix(c(0,1,1,0), 2, 2)
st_geometry(data) = drev
```

It would be great if you could make your dataset availabe in some form, with PROJ 6 and WKT2 axis order should be taken care of, hopefully also by sf.